# How to use CKEditor to post on the same page without refresh?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

[CKEditor http://www.homestayterendak.com/images/ckeditor.gif](http://www.homestayterendak.com/images/ckeditor.gif)

Comment: For clarification, should the text from the CKEditor also be put into a database? If not there is no need for an AJAX call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="CKEditor"></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="result-container"></div>
```

**jQuery**

Note, the result of the AJAX call I've set as HTML. This gives you a chance to check the HTML which has been posted for any malicious script on the server side; allowing someone to enter a `<script />` tag straight into the DOM of your page is NOT a good idea.

```
$(function() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('CKEditor'); // define CKEditor 

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var text = editor.getData(); // Use CKEditor inbuilt functionality to get the content
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myscript.aspx",
            data: "text=" + text,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#text-container").append(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i've tried something similar but it doesn't work. you can use this technique on simple input tag, but it doesnt't work with ckeditor.

Comment: Isn't the data supposed to be URL compatible? In other words: URL escape the text contents.

Comment: Alternatively, and probably a better idea: use an object for the data: 
`data: { text: text },` . jQuery will take care of the escaping.